# how to get value of a column and update another column in a single query?

Tags: mysql

How to set whether_displayed to 1 while executing this query ?

```
 select message 
 from commands 
 where whether_executed=1 
 and whether_displayed=0 
 and from_who='".$user_id."' 
 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: try sub query to do so

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is pretty much meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

after this you can run an update query like this

```
 UPDATE commands SET whether_displayed=1
 WHERE whether_executed=1 
 AND from_who='".$user_id."'
```

or this

```
 UPDATE commands 
 SET whether_displayed=1
 WHERE message IN (
 SELECT message FROM (
     SELECT message FROM commands 
     where whether_executed=1 
     and whether_displayed=0 
     and from_who='".$user_id."' 
     LIMIT 1
 ) tmp
 );
```

Comment: So I have to do another update query Right ? Is there any way to do that in a single query ? (select + update ) ?

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
  UPDATE commands SET whether_displayed= '1' 
   WHERE from_who='".$user_id."' = (
          SELECT from_who
          FROM commands 
          where whether_executed=1 
          LIMIT 1
        );
```

some additional lines or changes in this query need as per your need